# checking whether 4 points in a plane define a square?

Tags: c

how to check whether 4 points in the plane define a square? what's the function which given a point and a value of the area of a square as input parameters returns four squares(define a corresponding type) with sides parallel to the x axis and y axis

this how i start:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
struct point{
float x;
float y;
}
typedef struct point POINT;
struct square{
struct point p1;
struct point p2;
struct point p3;
struct point p4;
}
typedef struct square SQUARE;

int main()
{
int point;
printf("point coordinate");
printf("\n\n");

printf("enter data\n");
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: The current code doesn't compile.

Comment: Does the square have to be aligned to x- and y-axes?

Answer (score 4):

Calculate all 6 squared distances between each pair of points. Ie:

```
(x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)
```

Sort them.
Four smallest of them should be (approximately) equall and two greater should be (approximately) twice as big.

Do you need a measure of "how square is the square" ?

Comment: i should  input a point and an area (which allows me to work out the side length).then i am required to generate four squares. Each is required to have one corner on the point i input, and their sides must be parallel to either x or y axis.
@Łukasz Lew: it's my first year in the faculty of electronic and information technology of politechnika, things are tough for me here..i don't understand well the professor cause i don't speak polish to have extra explanation :(((

Comment: I really like your method.  As a slight variation, you can calculate the dot products for the six vectors.  Four of them should come out to (approximately) zero, and the other two should be (approximately) equal at (approximately) 1/sqrt(2).

Comment: Dot product of two vectors can calculated as ...

(x2 - x1) * (x3 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y3 - y1) + (z2 - z1) * (z3 * z1)

That uses points P1, P2 and P3 where vector1 = (P2 - P1) and Vector2 = (P3 - P1).

Answer (score 1):

1. Pick p1, and make it the origin, i.e. translate every point by -p1.
2. Let p2 be the next point closest to p1.  (Fixed in response to Paul R's observation.)
3. Take the angle theta between p1 and p2, rotate all points by -theta.  At this stage, p1 and p2 form a horizontal line (assuming angle 0 is oriented East).
4. Test that p3 and p4 have the same y coordinate (within tolerance).
5. Test that p3 and p4 have the same x coordinates as as p1 and p2, in any order (within tolerance).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you can make any assumptions about the ordering of the points. If not then there will be two operations:

1. firstly sort the points by X, Y
2. test for equal widths/heights (note that as you're using floats for your coordinates you'll probably need to define a small tolerance value when comparing for equality)

If the points are already known to be in a particular order then you can omit step 1.

(Note that this answer assumes that you are testing for a square which is in the same orientation as the X/Y axes - if the square can be rotated then by some arbitrary angle then it gets a little more complicated.)